# web3.py - sending signed transaction issue (transaction type not supported)

Tags: python, binance-smart-chain, web3py

I'm trying to send transaction from one account to another in Binance Smart Chain but I get error
`ValueError: {'code': -32000, 'message': 'transaction type not supported'}`

Here is my code

```
from web3 import Web3

REF_ADDRESS = '0x5...'
MY_ADDRESS = '0xe...'
MY_PKEY = 'd...'
MAX_GAS_ETHER = 0.0005

web3 = Web3(Web3.HTTPProvider('https://bsc-dataseed.binance.org/'))

balance = web3.eth.get_balance(MY_ADDRESS)
gas_price = float(web3.fromWei(web3.eth.gas_price, 'ether'))
allowed_gas = int(MAX_GAS_ETHER/gas_price)
print(web3.fromWei(balance, 'ether'))

tx = {
    'from': MY_ADDRESS,
    'to': REF_ADDRESS,
    'value': web3.toWei(0.0001, 'ether'),
    'gas': allowed_gas,
    'type': 2,
    'chainId': web3.eth.chain_id,
    'maxFeePerGas': web3.toWei(5, 'gwei'),
    'maxPriorityFeePerGas': web3.toWei(2, 'gwei'),
    'nonce': web3.eth.get_transaction_count(MY_ADDRESS),
    }

tx_signed = web3.eth.account.sign_transaction(tx, MY_PKEY)
tx_hash = web3.eth.send_raw_transaction(tx_signed.rawTransaction)
tx_receipt = web3.eth.wait_for_transaction_receipt(tx_hash)
```

Please help me figure up what I'm doing wrong

Answer (score 1):

Well, I solved the issue by changing transaction values from

```
tx = {
    'from': MY_ADDRESS,
    'to': REF_ADDRESS,
    'value': web3.toWei(0.0001, 'ether'),
    'gas': allowed_gas,
    'type': 2,
    'chainId': web3.eth.chain_id,
    'maxFeePerGas': web3.toWei(250, 'gwei'),
    'maxPriorityFeePerGas': web3.toWei(2, 'gwei'),
    'nonce': web3.eth.get_transaction_count(MY_ADDRESS),
    }
```

to

```
tx = {
    'nonce': web3.eth.get_transaction_count(MY_ADDRESS),
    'to': REF_ADDRESS,
    'value': web3.toWei(0.001, 'ether'),
    'gas': allowed_gas,
    'gasPrice': web3.eth.gas_price
}
```